# duplicates for linkedhashmap

Tags: java, duplicates, linkedhashmap

For the data that I am inputting into my program, I require duplicates, values for each item of data and I require the iteration order of the data to by insertion order as a default.

This is the kind of data that I am working with:

```
y = m * x + c
y = 8, m = 3, x = 2, c = 2
```

What I have been using up until now is a linkedHashMap to store all my data, which satisfies all my criteria other than storing duplicates.

So if I had **b + b = c** I wouldn't be able to get my program to work.

Preferably I would like to continue using maps for the key and value property and the ability to store different kinds if data i.e. String, Integer. So I would prefer a way for a linkedhashmap to retain duplicates. If there isn't, please let me know if there is any other way I can meet all my requirements.

Regards

Comment: Java does not allow duplicates in the key field of Map. **An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value**. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: Why you need a map to store values. Even you can use a class for storing values when you have "fixed set" of parameters..e.g. y,m,x,c. You can pass a class or primitive to a method to complete the functionality. And also, You can control the no of input.

Comment: I am taking my values from file input and the input is highly varied. It was pretty easy to set up a linkedHashMap to store all my data, and I need my data to make links between each other. It is a little complicated. That is why I decided to take the route that I have taken.

Comment: Guessing, You are using LinkedHashMap to retain the order of inputs. 
How linkedHashMap is easier than Storing value in a class? You can use constructor and method to store the values instead of calling 5 times put method of linkedhashmap.

Comment: Yes based on my above question it would be easier, but for my purposes and complexity of data, it is more time consuming. Unfortunately this is probably the route that I am going to have to take. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package com.shashi.mpoole;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class LinearEquation {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {


        LinearEquation linearEquation = new LinearEquation();
         InputStream in = LinearEquation.class.getResourceAsStream("../../../Inputs.txt");

            // Inputs Taken
            try {
                // Reading Inputs
                BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String line=null;
                // Separated by Comma m=4,x=2,c=5
                    while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                        LinearEqInput lei = new LinearEqInput();
                        String[] inputs = line.split(",");
                        //Getting array [m=4,x=2,c=5]
                        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

                            String[] keyval = inputs[i].split("=");
                            //Getting vallue [m,4]
                            linearEquation.setValue(lei, keyval[0], keyval[1]);

                        }
                        System.out.print("[Inputs: m= " + lei.m + " x= " + lei.x + " ,c= " + lei.c + "]");
                        //result
                        System.out.println(" Output :" + linearEquation.calculate(lei));

                    }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    }

    // This method use reflection to store the value of a field in the class LinearEqInput
    public void setValue(LinearEqInput lei,String fieldName, String value) throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException
    {
        Field f = lei.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        f.setDouble(lei, Double.parseDouble(value));

    }

    //Calculating the Y
    public double calculate(LinearEqInput lei)
    {
        return lei.m*lei.x + lei.c;
    }



}



class LinearEqInput
{
//Inputs
    double m,x,c = 0;

}
```

Inputs File

```
m=4,x=3,c=1
m=4,x=4,c=6
m=4,x=5,c=5
m=4,x=7,c=4
m=4,x=2,c=3
m=4,x=5,c=2
```

Output:

```
[Inputs: m= 4.0 x= 3.0 ,c= 1.0] Output :13.0
[Inputs: m= 4.0 x= 4.0 ,c= 6.0] Output :22.0
[Inputs: m= 4.0 x= 5.0 ,c= 5.0] Output :25.0
[Inputs: m= 4.0 x= 7.0 ,c= 4.0] Output :32.0
[Inputs: m= 4.0 x= 2.0 ,c= 3.0] Output :11.0
[Inputs: m= 4.0 x= 5.0 ,c= 2.0] Output :22.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, you have saved me a lot of time. For some reason  your getResourceAsStream doesn't work on my side, but fixed that with a dataInput and fileInput stream. Have an idea on how to integrate this with my pre-existing code =D thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use Guava library Multimap with value type of Object. Check their [documentation](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) for more info.

```
  Multimap map = ArrayListMultimap.create();
  map.put(key, value1);
  map.put(key, value2);
  List values = map.get(key);
```

Comment: Thanks, from what I have read it does seem to be fine. What does it mean depending on the implementation, the MultiMap will or will not allow duplicated. If I have duplicates in my data will this be automatic?

Comment: It is essentially a map of lists. So you can have a varying number of values under each key.

Comment: What is the syntax for a multimap. If I put `MultiMap mhm = new MultiHashMap();` it gives me an error with the only option being to create a class called MultiMap

Comment: ArrayListMultimap<K,V>.create()

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map<Integer,List<Integer>>` . In this datatype , you can store multiple values for the same key.Your put method can be like this ...

```
    public void put(Integer key,Integer val){
     List<Integer> arr = map.get(key);
     if(arr == null){
      arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      map.put(key,arr);
     }
     arr.add(val);
    }
```